# At least one prime between $\sqrt{n}$ and $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that for all $n>2$ there exists at least one prime $p$ such that $\sqrt{n}<p<n$ using elementary methods.

My try: If not, $\sum_{p<\sqrt{n}} (\lfloor n/p \rfloor-\lfloor \sqrt{n}/p \rfloor) \geq n-\sqrt{n}$  then...?

Comment: Even stronger: Chebyshev's theorem: There is a prime between $n$ and $2n$. There is a completely elementary proof by P. Erdös, essentially analyzing prime factors of ${2n\choose n}$.

Comment: So I know about Chebyshev... but not the proof. Is the proof complicated? Is there a simple one for the problem I stated?

Comment: I said elementary, but it certainly is not *easy*. I'm sure for this weaker result there is an "easier" proof.

Comment: Yes, I expect an easy proof.

Comment: But you **must** go read that proof by Erdös, it's one of the coolest ideas ever!

Comment: @TooOldForMath I think it's Bertrand postulated. Tchebychev gave an analytic proof of the postulate.

Comment: @Julien Yes that is correct, Chebyshev's theorem is sometimes also called Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: @nayrb I suggest you look at the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) and simplify it to give the weaker result, i.e. look at ${n\choose \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}$ instead. Several of the estimates should then be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a full answer, but hopefully helpful progress:

Look at  $M_p := \binom{p^2}{p~p~\ldots~p} = \frac{p^2!}{p!^p}$ where $p$ is a prime number,
let $v_q(x)$ the q-adic valuation of $M_p$ :
$$
v_q(M_p) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \lfloor\frac{p^2}{q^k}\rfloor - p\lfloor \frac{p}{q^k}\rfloor \leq (p-1)\lfloor \log_q(p^2) \rfloor
$$
Thus,
$$
 q^{v_q(M_p)} \leq p^{2(p-1)}
$$
In particular, if the interval $\{p+1,\ldots,p^2\}$ does not include any prime number, then
$$
M_p \leq p^{2(p-1)\pi(p)}
$$
where $\pi(p)$ is the number of prime numbers is the interval $\{1,\ldots,p\}$.

Moreover we know that $\ln(n!) \sim n \ln(n)$.Thus,
$$
\ln(M_p) \sim p^2 \ln(p)
$$
Because $2(p-1)\pi(p) \ln(p)$ is very small compared to $p^2 \ln(p)$

We know that your inequality will be true from a certain rank. Finding explicit bounds for a similar result to $\ ln (n!) \sim n \ ln (n)$, we will win...

Edit:

$$n \ln(n) \geq \ln(n!) \geq \frac{2n}{3} \ln(\frac{n}{3})
$$

Then,
$$
\ln(M_p) \geq \frac{9p^2}{10} \ln(\frac{p^2}{10}) - p^2 \ln(p) = \frac{p^2}{10} (8\ln(p) - 9 \ln(10))
$$
**Therefore**, $\ln(M_p) \geq \frac{p^2}{2} \ln(p)$ when $p \geq 10^3$, i.e. $\ln(p)\geq 3\ln(10)$.

Yet,
$$\pi(n) \leq 4 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{3} \frac{4}{5} \frac{6}{7} (n+1) = 4 + \frac{8(n+1)}{35}$$
for all integer n$\geq 0$.

Thus,

$$\frac{p^2}{2} \ln(p) \leq \ln(M_p) \leq \frac{2}{35}(p-1)(8p+140)\ln(p)$$

In the same way,
$$
35 p^2 \leq 4(p-1)(8p+140)
$$
ie
$$
0 \geq 35p^2-4(p-1)(8p+140) =3p^2-528p+560 > 3((p-88)^2-88^2)
$$

Therefore $p < 176$

Thus , it is known that the interval $ \{p+1,\ldots,p^2-1\}$ has a prime number when $p \geq 10^3$

but $3, 7, 47, 1009$ are prime numbers.

**So the interval $\{p +1, \ldots , p ^ 2-1 \}$ has a prime number when $p \geq 2$ . This completes your exercise .**

Answer (score 1):

By way of a bump, I'm answering my question to give two facts and hope someone can give a good answer from this or at least convince me it will be too hard to do.

The first is that if $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes then the claim is true. This is because if both $p,q<\sqrt{n}$ we get $n<n$.

The second is that the statement is equivalent to proving that if $p$ is a prime, the next prime $q$ is $q<p^2$. That is, the statement holds if it holds for $n=p^2$, $p$ prime. One does an induction argument, assuming there is a prime $p$ with $\sqrt{n}<p<n$, and then consider the interval $\sqrt{n+1}$ to $n+1$. If it doesn't contain a prime, it must be because $\sqrt{n}<p \leq \sqrt{n+1}$. Squaring gives the conclusion $n+1=p^2$, reducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm close to a complete answer, using only elementary arguments.

Denote by $\pi(n)$ the number of primes leq $n$ and let $k=\pi(\sqrt n)$ be the number of primes $\leq\sqrt n$. Also, let $p_1<\ldots<p_k\leq \sqrt n$ be all such primes.

We want to show that $K=\pi(n)-\pi(\sqrt n)\geq 1$ for all $n$.
Counting non-primes by using the principle of inclusion and exclusion, one can show that
$$\pi(n)-\pi(\sqrt n)+1 =n-\sum_{1\leq i\leq k}[n/p_i] + \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k}[n/p_ip_j]-\ldots+(-1)^k[n/p_1\cdots p_k].$$
Therefore, we want to show 
$$K=n-1-\sum_{1\leq i\leq k}[n/p_i] + \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq k}[{n\over p_{i_1}p_{i_2}}]-\ldots+(-1)^k[{n\over p_1\cdots p_k}]\geq 1.$$

Observe that $${n\over p_{i_1}\cdots p_{i_s}}
\geq [{n\over p_{i_1}\cdots p_{i_s}}]>{n\over p_{i_1}\cdots p_{i_s}}-1$$ and there are ${k\choose s}$ such terms in each sum. Replacing [] with the upper bound for odd $s$ and with the lower bound for even $s$ we get
\begin{align*}
K&=n-1-\sum_{1\leq i\leq k}[n/p_i] + \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq k}[{n\over p_{i_1}p_{i_2}}]-\ldots+(-1)^k[{n\over p_1\cdots p_k}]\\
&\geq n-\sum_{1\leq i\leq k}n/p_i + \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq k}{n\over p_{i_1}p_{i_2}}-\ldots+(-1)^k{n\over p_1\cdots p_k}-{k\choose 0}-{k\choose 2} -{k\choose 4}-\ldots\\
&=n\prod_{i=1}^k(1-1/p_i)-2^{k-1}.
\end{align*} 
Hopefully, induction can save us now to prove $K\geq 1$ for all $n$...