# Is the square of a prime necessarily larger than the next prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $p_n$ represent the $n$th prime number.  Is the following formula necessarily true?

$$p_n^2 > p_{n+1}$$

Experimentally, it seems true but I don't know enough number theory to prove it.  My problem is that I don't know enough number theory to relate primes to each other.  I know enough math to use the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) to prove it for sufficiently large $n$ but I can't prove it in general.

My question is whether this relationship is true in general and, if so, what is a proof for this result?

Thank you...

Comment: Should follow from Bertrand s postulate

Comment: Yes, as Shailesh said, Bertrand's postulate (and the fact that $p_n \geq 2$) implies that $p_{n+1} < 2p_n \leq p_n^2$.

Comment: As mentioned, from Bertrand's postulate you actually have much much better bound - $p_{n+1}<2p_n$ which is much much smaller especially for large prime numbers.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669017 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38137